# How to modify parent entities on child updates? (one to many)

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am developing a .net core 2.2 web api with .net EF core and I have a table for Tasks and a table for Rejects.

Each task can have 0 or more rejects and each Reject has one task.

(Task 1<--->* Reject)

Each reject has one of two statuses: REJECT_TODO, REJECT_DONE.

Each task has one of three statuses: TODO, DONE, REJECTED.

The following behavior is desired:
If a task has a reject that has a status: REJECT_TODO then it is REJECTED.

If a task has no rejects or only reject that has a status: REJECT_DONE then it could be either TODO/DONE.

Also the rejects that are pulled from the database for the check are not updated with the current changes so updated/deleted reject will appear unchanged.

(Default status after beeing REJECTED is TODO)

I want all of this to be automatic for any CRUD operation on a Reject.

I have already tried iterating changes for Reject entity in DbContext::SaveChanges.

The issue is I need to query the database for a non-updated Task entity and perform Update for the task which will override any changes already made to it for the current SaveChanges call.

I can not put it my DAL because of the same reason.

```cs
    public class Task
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }

        public TaskStatus Status { get; set; }

        public List<Reject> Rejects { get; set; }  
    }

    public class Reject
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public RejectStatus Status { get; set; }

        public Guid TaskId { get; set; }
    }

    public enum TaskStatus
    {
        TODO, DONE, REJECTED
    }

    public enum RejectStatus
    {
        REJECT_TODO, REJECT_DONE
    }
```

Expected results:

Create: if a Reject is added to a Task (with REJECT_TODO by default) then the parent Task will be REJECTED

Delete/Update: if a Reject is deleted/updated from a Task then if there are no more rejects with status REJECT_TODO for that task it will be TODO

Thanks! :)